# How to keep the dockable bar of dotnetbar visible in auto-hide state until i click other controls?

Tags: c#, dockable, dotnetbar

Just like the title says. I create a dockable bar, one of dotnetbar controls in the form.And I set the bar in auto-hide state. Now I want to keep the bar visible in auto-hide state until I click other controls just like the visual studio's dockable bars.

I have tried to set the property "AutoHideVisible" true, but it just let the bar display in a very short time and then hide later.

```
dockableBar.AutoHideVisible = true;
```